Creating a fifo stock aging that ignores inventory transfer dates but keeps the quantity impact
I am trying to create a stock aging report that calculates how much stock is available on hand and place available quantity in aging brackets based on their submission/in date (FIFO method).
My issue is sometimes there are these internal inventory transfers that moves quantities from one to another, which means that the location of the available quantity has changed but the quantity aging didn't.
Here is an example of my data



Trans #.
Transaction Type
Posting Date
Item Code
Warehouse
Flow
Quantity
Aging (FIFO)




64
Receipt
12/31/2013
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1044
-25998


19195
Purchase
1/1/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-24798


19336
Purchase
1/7/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-23598


19478
Purchase
1/13/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-22398


19549
Purchase
1/15/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-21198


19575
Purchase
1/16/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-19998


54051
Issue
1/31/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
Out
-6831
-19998


20011
Purchase
2/1/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-18798


20064
Purchase
2/3/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-17598


20090
Purchase
2/4/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-16398


20142
Purchase
2/5/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-15198


20157
Purchase
2/6/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-13998


20465
Purchase
2/20/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1000
-12998


54211
Issue
2/28/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
Out
-6351
-12998


20739
Purchase
3/1/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
240
-12758


20755
Purchase
3/2/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
240
-12518


20811
Purchase
3/4/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
240
-12278


20812
Purchase
3/4/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-11078


20829
Purchase
3/5/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-9878


20834
Purchase
3/6/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-8678


20875
Purchase
3/8/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-7478


20929
Purchase
3/9/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
280
-7198


21127
Purchase
3/17/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-5998


54394
Issue
3/31/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
Out
-6930
-5998


21562
Purchase
4/1/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-4798


21607
Purchase
4/2/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-3598


21707
Purchase
4/6/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-2398


21796
Purchase
4/10/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
-1198


21991
Purchase
4/18/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1200
2


22159
Purchase
4/25/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
In
1000
1002


54562
Issue
4/30/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
Out
-6930
1002


54716
Issue
5/30/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
Out
-115.53
886.47


1052
Inventory Transfer
6/6/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse A
Out
-212
674.47


1053
Inventory Transfer
6/6/2014
ITEM0001
Warehouse B
In
212
886.47



My end goal is to show that as of the 6th of June there is 674.47 available Quantity in Warehouse A and 212 Available in Warehouse B. Both quantities should be in the 2 months old bracket because if you follow the Aging bracket which is deducting the total out quantity from the Inflow transactions from oldest to newest and stops at Trans # 54716 which is where the last quantity has gone out. Meaning the remaining quantity is from Trans # 22159 which came in on the 25th of April, so actual aging should be around 40-50 days, but instead it shows 0 days for 212 of that quantity due to that inventory transfer happening on the 6th. What I am trying to achieve is to show the correct Onhand which is 212 in Warehouse B and 674 in Warehouse A but at the same time show the correct aging bracket which is 2 Months rather than 0 days if I am running the report on the 6th.
Below is my current query:
WITH "StockDetails" AS
(
SELECT


"Qty" ,
"Value",
"Date" ,
"ItemCode" ,
"Warehouse",
"Flow" ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "ItemCode","Warehouse" ORDER BY "Date","Qty" DESC) AS "ROW_NUM" 
FROM (

SELECT

SUM("Quantity") AS "Qty",
0 AS "Value",
[Posting Date] AS "Date",
T0."ItemCode",
T0.Warehouse,

"Flow" 

FROM (SELECT "Item Code" as ItemCode,"Warehouse","Posting Date","Quantity","Flow" FROM OINM WHERE [Transaction Type] <> 'Inventory Transfer' AND "Posting Date" <= '20140606'
) T0



GROUP BY 

[Posting Date],
T0."ItemCode",
T0.Warehouse,
"Flow"

) S0

),


    "ItemEndTotal" AS (
    
SELECT
"ItemCode" ,
"Warehouse",
SUM("Qty") AS "FinalCount",
SUM("Value") AS "FinalValue"

FROM "StockDetails"
GROUP BY "Warehouse","ItemCode"
    ),

    
"ReverseRunningTotal" AS (

SELECT

"ItemCode" ,
"Warehouse",
"Flow",
"Date" ,
"Qty" ,
"Value",
SUM("Qty") OVER (PARTITION BY "ItemCode","Warehouse" ORDER BY "Date" ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS "ReverseTotal",
SUM("Value") OVER (PARTITION BY "ItemCode","Warehouse" ORDER BY "Date" ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS "ReverseTotalV" 

FROM "StockDetails"

WHERE "Flow" = 'In'
),

    "FindDate" AS (
    
SELECT DISTINCT 

"T"."ItemCode",
"T"."Warehouse",
"FinalCount" ,
"FinalValue" ,
LAST_VALUE("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY "P"."ItemCode","P"."Warehouse" ORDER BY "Date" ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )AS "TheDate"     

FROM "ItemEndTotal" AS "T" 
JOIN "ReverseRunningTotal" AS "P" ON "T"."ItemCode" = "P"."ItemCode" AND "T"."Warehouse" = "P"."Warehouse" AND "P"."ReverseTotal" >= "T"."FinalCount" 
) 



SELECT

T0."ItemCode",
T0."Warehouse",
T0."Date" as "DocDate" ,
CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY,T0."Date",'20140606')/30) < 6 THEN (DATEDIFF(DAY,T0."Date",'20140606')/30) 
     WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY,T0."Date",'20140606')/30) between 6 and 12 then 12
     WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY,T0."Date",'20140606')/30) between 13 and 24 then 24
      end as "AGE_BUCKET",
DATEDIFF(d,T0."Date",'20140606') AS "AgedDays",
CASE WHEN "TheDate" = "P"."Date" THEN "FinalCount" - ( "ReverseTotal" - T0."Qty" ) ELSE T0."Qty" END AS "InQty",
CASE WHEN "TheDate" = "P"."Date" THEN "FinalValue" - ( "ReverseTotalV" - T0."Value" ) ELSE T0."Value" END AS "StockValuation",
NULL AS "RowNo"

FROM "StockDetails" T0 
LEFT JOIN "FindDate" ON T0."ItemCode" = "FindDate"."ItemCode" AND T0."Warehouse" = "FindDate"."Warehouse"
LEFT JOIN "ReverseRunningTotal" "P" ON T0."ItemCode" = "P"."ItemCode" AND T0."Warehouse" = "P"."Warehouse" AND T0."Flow" = "P"."Flow" AND T0."Date" = "P"."Date" AND T0."Qty" = "P"."Qty" AND T0."Value" = "P"."Value"

WHERE T0."Qty" >= 0 AND T0."Date" >= "FindDate"."TheDate" AND "FinalCount" > 0 
GO


Now if I remove the inventory transfers I get correct aging but wrong onhand as it all appears in warehouse A, and if I put it on I get correct onhand but wrong aging as 212 appear under 0 days. I have tried several solutions like creating an aging function inside the aging and joining it through an outer apply duplicating the transfers to the number of rows of available quantities before the date of the transfer and then replacing the quantity and the dates of the transfer lines with the oldest date of an available quantity but the performance was awful and it took over 15 mins to run and wasn't very accurate.
Any ideas would be appreciated.
My current output if I remove inventory transfers looks like this



ItemCode
Warehouse
DocDate
AGE_BUCKET
AgedDays
InQty
StockValuation
RowNo




ITEM0001
Warehouse A
2014-04-25
1
42
674.47
0
NULL


ITEM0001
Warehouse B
2014-06-06
0
0
212
0
NULL



And my desired output is as follows



ItemCode
Warehouse
DocDate
AGE_BUCKET
AgedDays
InQty
StockValuation
RowNo




ITEM0001
Warehouse A
2014-04-25
1
42
674.47
0
NULL


ITEM0001
Warehouse B
2014-04-25
1
42
212
0
NULL




What happens if there were some pieces in WarehB already? I think you can calculate the aging thing outside of your CTE by just taking the MAX date of the last In-transaction where the transaction isn't a transfer, although this gets complicated if there's a lot of transfers going on. For a reasonable advanced warehouse, i'd think you're smoked, so just don't do this age thing

it will be easier for others to help you if you provide the sample data in consumable format (DML)

@siggemannen I thought of that, but taking the last in date is not accurate, because you could have 1000 onhand and sell just 10 1 day before the transfer date, and then transfer 900, and the 1000 onhand could have 10 different sources. Then you're left with the same problem, that all of your quantities are now aging on the date of that 100 sale.

Like I said, don't do aging :) I remember that stock valuation routine at our previous place of business was by far the messiest parts of the system, using nested cursors and whatnot. Although, that was before window functions were a thing

What is aging (age)? Something like in PartyNumber?
